# Pyspark dataframe: load from csv and then remove the first line

Tags: python-3.x, azure, csv, pyspark, databricks

I am able to load csv file from Azure datalake into pyspark dataframe.
How to remove the first line and make the second line as my header?

I have seen some RDD solution. But I am not able to load the file and I get error using the following code as "RDD is empty"

```
items = sc.textFile(f"abfss://{container}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/tmp/items.csv")
firstRow=data.first()
```

Hence I prefer to load using standard spark as below. I could display the dataframe contents. I have to drop or remove the first line and make 2nrd row as header. Thanks.

```
items= spark.read.format("csv").load(f"abfss://{container}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/tmp/items.csv", header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

it's not an optimized solution but will solve the requirement.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)],['a','b','c'])
df.show()
```

[image]

```
df1 = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF().where(F.col('_2') > 0).drop('_2')
for each_col in df.columns:
     df1 = df1.withColumn(each_col, F.col('_1.'+each_col))

df1.drop('_1').show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get an error as below "AssertionError: col should be Column"

Comment: check this solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to drop/remove the first line and make my second row as the header.